# How can i manage selenium error 10054 properly?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

How can I better manage (ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError (10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None) properly?  More specifically, also include a progressive delay of (1,2,4,8,16,32,...) seconds.

```
import csv
from time import sleep
from parsel import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
with open('input_stock master.csv', 'r') as inFile3:
    fileReader = csv.DictReader(inFile3)
    for row in fileReader:
        ticker = row['ticker']
        # has created 10054 error
        driver.get('https://f.y.com/' + ticker)

        #has created 10054 error
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Download Data"]').click()
driver.quit()
inFile3.close()
```

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: What do you mean by _manage selenium error 10054 properly?_ ?

Comment: back ground info regarding remote host shutting down the connection  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333671/how-to-solve-the-10054-error